# mongodump using gzip in mongodb 3.2

Tags: mongodb

How can I dump and restore mongodb database 3.2

I have use below command.

```
mongodump --db <yourdb> --gzip --archive=/data/backups/
```

But it says, ERROR: unknown option gzip.

I have already install gzip

Comment: Check with mongodump --version which version you use, it should be larger or equal than 3.2.

Comment: I have the same issiue

Answer (score 0):

Need install mongodb-org

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```